# mod rewrite rule won't work - apache .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, flask

I have a simple Flask app, I changed the Apache config file to enable the .htaccess and I assume that the file is seen by Apache as when I write "Deny from all" in .htaccess I get a "Forbidden" page. This makes me think that I must have an error somewhere in the syntax. I spent many hours trying different RegEx but to no avail.

I would like to convert the current URL:

http://example.com/average_temperatures?city1=istanbul&city2=ankara&city3=london

To this format:

http://example.com/average_temperatures/istanbul/ankara/london

This is the content of my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^average_temperatures/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ average_temperatures?city1=$1&city2=$2&city3=$3 [L]
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction what might be off here? I appreciate any hints. Thx.

Comment: Take a look into your http servers error log file to make sure no error is thrown. Then enable rewrite logging, this allows you to understand what is going on inside your rewrite engine.

Comment: Take a clear look on the substitution pattern of the RewriteRule, "average_temperatures **.ext** ?city1=$1&city2=$2&city3=$3" you have missed the file extension( **.php** or **.jsp** ) of the file for which you are passing the get parameters(query string values)

Comment: Hey, the page is generated by a Flask app, so I guess the extension is simply ".html" (even though it's not visible in the URL), but I tried it (average_temperatures.html?city1=$1&city2=$2&city3=$3 [L] ) but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this lovely site to debug your htaccess rule: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ - accordingly, your rule matches. So the Issue is something else. (Maybe you missunderstood the purpose of url-rewrites?)

Your rule perfectly rewrites the EXTERNAL request

```
http://weather-averages.co.uk/average_temperatures/istanbul/ankara/london
```

to

```
http://weather-averages.co.uk/average_temperatures?city1=istanbul&city2=ankara&city3=london
```

Keep in mind, that this rule is not applied for Links you place inside your html. You need to change your `<a href="">`s to target the SEO-Url, you want to provide:

```
<a href="http://weather-averages.co.uk/average_temperatures/istanbul/ankara/london">
```

will then be rewritten, so that you have the following `$_GET`-Array available:

```
$_GET = array (
   "city1" => "istanbul",
   "city2" => "ankara",
   "city3" => "london"
);
```

ps.: On your rewrite rule, you are missing the extension - maybe this is your issue?

```
average_temperatures?city1=$1&city2=$2&city3=$3 [L]
average_temperatures.php?city1=$1&city2=$2&city3=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Dognose,
I was hoping I had an error in the RegEx which would be the easy to fix, but as the rule matches and .htaccess is enabled, I fear the issue lies somewhere deeper than this.
Could you clarify what you mean by “external request?. Sorry if this question sounds dumb but I’m just starting out and it’s my first hobby project. Also, it shouldn’t rewrite from /istanbul/ankara into ?city1=Istanbul&city2=Ankara&, but the other way round, right?
It’s a Flask app, with dynamically generated content, and I tried adding “.html” to the rule but it didn’t work either.

Comment: @scott_m It seems like your confusion is about the url rewrite. Your server just understands ONE language: This is the `?city=1&city=2` style. But you want your visitors to SEE the `/ankara/istanbul` style - (this is what I call "external" URL). So, your htaccess needs to translate the Visitors request (external url) to something your server can understand (`?`-style). So it should EXACTLY rewrite this way.

Comment: @scott_m It is quite confussion, I know: Default is `?mode=xy`. So, one might assume, that url rewrite needs to change `?mode=xy` to `/xy` - but it works the other way round, always in "request-direction": Visitor calls `/xy` - so, htaccess needs to make `?mode=xy` out of it, so your server can understand it.